# Deleting row index in data frame in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in **python** like below

```
ID  Featurename  TerminalName   NBBikes  NBEmptydoc   UploadDate    lat    lon

2   XXXXX           XXXXX           XXX     XXX          XXX         X      X

3   XXXXX           XXXXX            XX     XXX          XXX        X       X
```

and i am exporting this data frame to csv file using below command:

```
csvdf.to_csv('./en_final_table_2.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-32')
```

while exporting i don't want the ID column in my csv file, is there a way to do this?
Please help.

Comment: Use "`" symbols to paste in your code for better visibility and modify it so it's readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'ID' is in the index, then you can use `index=False`:

```
csvdf.to_csv('./en_final_table_2.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-32', index=False)
```